# PHP Find value in array and echo something different

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$media = $db->query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_photos WHERE user_id='".$profile->id."' LIMIT 20");
$picheck = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$profile->id."'");
$picheck = $picheck->fetch_object();

if($media->num_rows == 0) { 
$uploaded_photos = 0;
} else {
$uploaded_photos = array();
while($photo = $media->fetch_object()) {
    $photos[] = array('type'=>'uploaded','id' => $photo->id, 'path' => $photo->path);
}
} 
//IN A RELATED PHP FILE:
<?php
     $c=0;
     if(!empty($photos)) {
      for($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
        if($photos[$i]['type'] == 'instagram') { 

        } else {
          $c++;
          echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 thumbnail m-5">';
          echo '<div class="image-container">';
          echo '<img src="'.$system->getDomain().'/uploads/'.$photos[$i]['path'].'" class="img-responsive">';
          echo '
          <div class="caption">
          <h4>';
          //HERE IS MY PROBLEM, IF THE PATH OF THE USERS CURRENT PROFILE PHOTO IS THE SAME AS THE PATH OF THE PHOTO DISPLAYED, IT SHOULD ECHO SOMETHING DIFFERENT.
          if(in_array($picheck->profile_photo, $photos['path'], true)){ echo '<a href="#" class="no-underline pull-left"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-title="Your Profilepicture" placeholder="" data-original-title="" title=""></i> </a>';
          }
          else { echo '<a href="#" onclick="deletePhoto('.$photos[$i]['id'].')" class="no-underline pull-left"> <i class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-title="'.$lang['Delete_Photo'].'" placeholder="" data-original-title="" title=""></i> </a>';
          }
          echo '
          <a href="#" onclick="setAsProfilePhoto('.$photos[$i]['id'].')" class="no-underline pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-user" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-title="'.$lang['Profile_Photo'].'" placeholder="" data-original-title="" title=""></i> </a>
          </h4>
          </div>
          ';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
        }
      }
    }
      if($c==0) {
      echo 'YOU DONT HAVE ANY PICTURES';
    }
    ?>
```

I have been searching high and low to solve this, I hope someone can help me out. I would like to thank all who put efford in helping me out on this beforehand.

Comment: what you want do ? clear about your question

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I tried, it didn't work

Comment: @jothi as stated, //HERE IS MY PROBLEM, IF THE PATH OF THE USERS CURRENT PROFILE PHOTO IS THE SAME AS THE PATH OF THE PHOTO DISPLAYED, IT SHOULD ECHO SOMETHING DIFFERENT. So, if the users profile picture path which is set and stored in the db ($picheck->profile_picture) is the same as the path of $photos['path'] i want it to display a different icon and a different text for the tooltip.

Comment: @Aurora Do `var_dump($photos);` and see the array structure. `$photos['path']` is wrong because `$photos` array doesn't have an index named `path`. Error reporting would have told you about this. And if it's not turned on then add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: $photos[$i]['path']  is the value of this one is string so why passing string in in_array   you have to pass array not any value in second parameter

Comment: you have to pass full array  like this if(in_array($picheck->profile_photo, $photos, true))

Comment: in_array returns true if given value exists in given array

Comment: @RajdeepPaul First of all, thank you for teaching me something new. I added your code and error reporting gevis me::  Undefined property: stdClass::$profile_photo in <b>/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/layout/profile.php</b>  on line 422 Warning :  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in  <b>/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/layout/profile.php</b> on line 422

Comment: @Aurora I missed one important thing, the second argument of `in_array()` function should be an array, so the correct condition for *if* clause should be `if(in_array($picheck->profile_photo, $photos[$i], true)){...`

Comment: @jothi Thank you too, I tried your version, it didn't work

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thank you. i tried, it didn't work...

Comment: @Aurora Are you getting any error? Do `echo $picheck->profile_photo;` and `var_dump($photos);` and check whether you'll ever get a match in `in_array()` function or not.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul THANK YOU IT WORKS! And thank you again for teaching me about error reporting! $picheck->profile_photo was undefined. I checked the database and i missed 1 character. Excuse my mistake. How do i mark your awnser as solved?

Comment: @Aurora I've given an answer below, along with the explanation.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul marked it. Thanks again and have a fantastic day!

Comment: @Aurora You're welcome. Have a nice day. *Cheers!* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of this line,

```
if(in_array($picheck->profile_photo, $photos['path'], true)){ ...
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The second argument of `in_array()` function i.e `$photos['path']` is wrong because `$photos` array doesn't have an index named `path`.

So the correct condition for *if* block would be,

```
if(in_array($picheck->profile_photo, $photos[$i], true)){ ...
```